# How can I create json file for javascript coding?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

```
<script>

    d3.json("mydata2.json", function (data) {

        var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 500)

        canvas.selectAll("rect")        
            .data(data)
            .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("width", function(d) {return d.age *10; })
                .attr("height", 50)
                .attr("y", function(d, i) {return i*50; })
                .attr("fill", "blue")

    })          

</script>
```

I would like to run this code but after I run it didn't work.
I don't know how to create json file...
Can I create with notepad?

Comment: There are a million tutorials online on how to write JSON and JSON can be stored in the file you are referencing "mydata2.json" as a plain string. Another common tool is a JSON linter or formatter, try http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Simply create the file in your file explorer by naming it as .json and then paste the content in.